# Spring DTO: Cannot construct instance of <DTO interface>

Tags: java, spring, dto

I'm working with DTOs in Spring and facing an issue with the use of an [interface-based projection DTO](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections#interface-based-projections) while deserialization in the @RequestBody of a method of the `Controller` class.

It looks like that the use of projection based DTOs only works in one direction. Getting a DTO from the repository is pretty easy and handy:

```java
public interface ConditionRepository extends JpaRepository<Condition, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT c FROM Condition c WHERE c.controller.id = ?1")
    List<ConditionDto> findAllByControllerId(Long controllerId);

}
```

But if Spring tries to deserialize the same projection based DTO `ConditionDto` in the Controller class

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}/conditions", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public ResponseEntity<List<ConditionResult>> putConditions(@RequestBody List<ConditionDto> conditionList, @PathVariable("id") Long controllerId) {
    System.out.print("conditionList: ");
    System.out.println(conditionList);
    return null;
}
```

it throws an error:

```
Type definition error: [simple type, class dev.smarthome.weatherstation.condition.dto.ConditionDto];
nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException:
Cannot construct instance of `dev.smarthome.weatherstation.condition.dto.ConditionDto` 
(no Creators, like default constructor, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types,
have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
```

The error makes sense in that way that the DTO is an interface so Spring can not instantiate it.

What would be a good solution? Do I have to convert my implementation from projection based DTO to a class DTO so it can instantiate the DTO? Or did I forget something?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is write your own [HttpMessageConverter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#rest-message-conversion) and create new anonymous instances of your interface in there (basically deserializing the JSON manually and putting the corresponding fields in the getters). But I wouldn't recommend it.

Instead, ask yourself : why is this Dto an interface ? In the case of a projection it makes sense, but projections are meant to be ***read***, not written.

So it seems you have two solutions

- Either create a new object, which wouldn't be a projection but an actual object used for write (HTTP POST) purposes. Using the right semantics wouldn't be difficult here.
- Extend your interface with a dummy object which would be used only for deserialization purposes of write (HTTP POST) queries.

Comment: I've already created a dummy object that implements the interface `ConditionDto` so it can be instantiated. Looks like that would be a solution that works.